# Django Model *** IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Whenever I create an object,

```py
ModelName.objects.create(image = image, owner = user, cordinate_Y=cordinate_Y, cordinate_X=cordinate_X, agency=agency)

*** IndexError: list index out of range
```

here is model.py

```py
class ModelName(models.Model):
    image   = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_file_name_before, blank=False)
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=False, default='None')
    owner   = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False
    )
    ...
    extra_fields = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default='None')
    ...
    cordinate_X  = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    cordinate_Y  = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    agency       = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 'GENERAL', blank=False)
```

I have tried almost everything but actually not able to understand why I am getting stuck at this.

it's working fine if I create from Django admin though.

**EDIT**

If anyone has doubt that am I able to list the objects that are present in dB which I created from Django admin

```py
ModelName.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<ModelName: 3f6dd007-8b2e-409b-b0fa-9e2f07be1483>, <ModelName: e8233c47-f482-48cf-aa9a-cdcef86b55eb>]>
```

Thank you for reviewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's happening because you are not giving any `name` field in

```
ModelName.objects.create(image = image, owner = user, cordinate_Y=cordinate_Y, cordinate_X=cordinate_X, agency=agency)
```

but here you mentioned that

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=False, default='None')
```

now try by changing `blank = False` to `blank = True` ,
`name = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=False, default='None')`